# Downgrade from 17.10 to 16.04LTS

Tags: downgrade

How do I downgrade from 17.10 to 16.04LTS since I can't be upgraded to 18.04 due to my 32-bit laptop?

Comment: What laptop / processor do you have?

Comment: Are you sure that you "can't be upgraded to 18.04 due to 32-bit laptop"? My understanding is that Canonical Ltd. has stopped providing 32-bit **iso images** since Ubuntu 17.10, but they still support upgrading to the next release. How are you running 17.10 in the first place? There is no 32-bit iso for 17.10 too. Try `do-release-upgrade` for a few days. Usually release upgrade path is not opened immediately after a new release.

Comment: Bought the 32-bit laptop (Panasonic Toughbook Model CF-73) with 16.10, upgraded to 17.04, then 17.10 last Fall - figuring I'd FINALLY get an LTS on it with 18.04 and settle down - then told I can't upgrade my 32-bit to 18.04...

Answer (score 3):

**Ubuntu Version 18.04 LTS 32bit is supported**

You can upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 with the `do-release-upgrade`.

I upgraded a 16.04 LTS to 18.04 using this command:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

As Pomsky suggested, it's the 32bit iso that is not provided by Canonical.  The actual supported files are in the repository.

You will have to [wait a few days](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes) or use the `-d` option and get it immediately.

This is my installation mode:

```
$ file /lib/systemd/systemd
/lib/systemd/systemd: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=b6190e3094045363f5cca4d20db62b82aed17e4f, stripped
```

Comment: I've linked this Q&A from this question just now: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066360/upgrade-to-18-04-from-16-04-32-bits/1069582#1069582

Answer (score 0):

You need to backup all your important data into a external drive or cloud service, then you need to grab a 16.04 install disk, boot of it and then reinstall. You could try changing the repository info to 16.04 instead of 17.10 and then downgrading all the packages manually but that takes a long time. Plus there's the added risk of replacing a vital componet to the os when its in use and screwing your whole computer up. Don't take the downgrading way unless you're feeling brave.

Comment: While having backups is always good, it's not a requirement for preserving it.  Installing Ubuntu will not touch personal data unless the "format" option is specified for the partition.  If the format option isn't checked (which isn't by default) the install would only delete the directory that has system files.  No user data is in any of those directories.  You might consider adding some of these details to your answer.

Comment: Not worried about 'all my data', only want to keep all the applications and settings I've installed for 18 months and not have to hunt down, reinstall, hope I get it right without another big struggle,... looks like I can't actually downgrade, only trash and install older version.