# Upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04 32 bits

Tags: upgrade

I used Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32 bits. I have been notified that i can upgrade to 18.04. My question is that one: Which version of Ubuntu 18.04 will be installed, 32 bits or 64 bits?

Comment: Is your system 32bit as I doubt it has a 32bit version

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I've heard many people are getting update for 18.04 from in 16.04 32bit. But I doubt on the performance.

Comment: My computer is a 64 bit, but in 2012 i installed Ubuntu 12.04 32 bits. I upgraded 12.04 32 bit to 16.04 32 bits. This week my software updater send me a notification: Ubuntu 18.04 is avalaible... to Upgrade!!!

Comment: If your system is 64 bit then go for it!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if the CPU is 32-bit, you can't install a 64-bit OS on it.

Judging by the answers on [Is it possible to "upgrade" from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5018/301745) and [How can I switch a 32-bit installation to a 64-bit one?](https://askubuntu.com/q/81824/301745), it is very difficult to switch from 32- to 64-bit, so I can't imagine the upgrade would do it for you.

Comment: That's correct the release upgrader will not switch to 64 bit for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to answer on this question you can upgrade 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS with 32-bit support:

[Downgrade from 17.10 to 16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029183/downgrade-from-17-10-to-16-04lts)

There is a bit of confusion in this area.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 32-bit architecture and want Ubuntu 18.04 server then you can download 16.04 server and then look at upgrading online to ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is an English language question answer site. Please post in English. It is not clear if you are trying to provide a new solution to this question.